# Combine units in a shapefile while keeping others granular in R

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, shapefile, rgeo-shapefile

I have a 5-digit postcode shapefile for Germany. Big number 1-digits postcodes are similar to German states. I read shapefile data with `rgdal` thus having a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. I have only data for some part of Germany, i.e. some postcodes. The data I have I like to show on a granular 5-digit level. Using `leaflet` to create a map, it makes very long time for me, to plot all of the almost 10.000 postcodes. Thus I like to "summarize"/"combine"/"merge" the outer border of those postcodes where I don't have data (where the value is `NA`).

```
# German postcode shapes 

# Create temp files
temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()

# Download the zip file and save to 'temp' 
URL <- "https://downloads.suche-postleitzahl.org/v2/public/plz-5stellig.shp.zip"
download.file(URL, temp)

# Unzip the contents of the temp and save unzipped content in 'temp2'
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)

# Read shape file 
library(rgdal)
GER_postcode <- readOGR(temp2)

head(GER_postcode@data$note)

# Create subsample 
library(tidyverse)

GER_postcode@data$einwohner2 <- ifelse(substr(GER_postcode@data$plz, 1, 1) %in% c("0", "1", "7"), GER_postcode@data$einwohner, NA)

# Plot Subsample 
library(leaflet)

qpal <- colorBin("Reds", GER_postcode@data$einwohner2, bins=10)

leaflet(GER_postcode) %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = TRUE,opacity = 1,fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              color="black",fillColor = ~qpal(einwohner2),weight = 1) %>%
  addLegend(values=~einwohner2,pal=qpal,title="Population")
```

How can I make the map show those postcode shapes with values and combine all other where the value is `NA`?

[image]

I was looking at `library(rgeos)` and `gUnaryUnion()` that units all units in a shapefile to outer borders. Although I only need to do this on a subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would use filter / subset to drop irrelevant polygons and use country outline as a separate background layer. Outline can be built by making an union of postcode shapes, though it's likely faster to download one (or install some package that bundles country shapes)

As `rgdal` and `regos` will be retired in just few months, the example below uses `sf` (and optional `geos` package ) instead.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

URL <- "https://downloads.suche-postleitzahl.org/v2/public/plz-5stellig.shp.zip"

# use GDAL virtual file systems to load zipped shapefile from remote url
GER_postcode <- paste0("/vsizip//vsicurl/", URL) %>%  read_sf()

# country outline from giscoR
GER_outline <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country = "DE")

# if it must be built from input shapes, we can use sf::st_union() or switch  
# to geos (the R library), it performs bit better in this case:

# GER_outline <- as_geos_geometry(GER_postcode) %>% 
#   geos_make_collection() %>% 
#   geos_unary_union() %>% 
#   st_as_sfc()

GER_postcode_subsample <- GER_postcode %>% filter(substr(plz, 1, 1) %in% c(0, 1, 7))

# Plot Subsample 
qpal <- colorBin("Reds", GER_postcode_subsample$einwohner, bins=10)

leaflet(GER_postcode_subsample) %>%
  addPolygons(data = GER_outline, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              color="black", fillColor = "#808080", weight = 1) %>% 
  addPolygons(stroke = TRUE,opacity = 1,fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              color="black",fillColor = ~qpal(einwohner),weight = .2) %>%
  # append NA to values to include it in legend
  addLegend(values=c(~einwohner, NA),pal=qpal,title="Population")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>